# TensorFlow serving on docker failed call to cuInit: CUresult(-1)

Tags: docker, tensorflow, kubernetes, tensorflow-serving

When using the image `tensorflow/serving:latest-devel-gpu` on Kuberenetes, the GPU isn't being used.

I don't do anything fancy with it, simply pass server.conf and model files.

The default runtime is nvidia-docker, and my other GPU pod is able to use the GPU.

The only error in the log:

> E
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:397
>   ] failed call to cuInit: CUresult(-1)

Something else which is interesting:

> I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189]
>   libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so
>   DSO loaded into this program

Answer (score 2):

update you dockerfile with

```
RUN rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so.1
```

or extend the serving devel gpu image from docker hub, with one extra line

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:1.9.0-devel-gpu
RUN rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues on the tracker: [#394](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/394),  [#2882](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2882), [#646](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/646).

In brief, there are solutions that work well (try one at a time):

1. Run:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe  
   $ sudo reboot
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   $ nvidia-cuda-mps-server
   ```
3. Run the [following](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/760872/ubuntu-12-04-error-cudagetdevicecount-returned-30/):

   ```
   $ sudo modinfo nvidia-<driver_version_num>-uvm (with driver_version_num as 384 in my case)
   $ sudo modprobe --force-modversion nvidia-<nvidia-version>-uvm
   ```
4. `I was on CUDA-8 and CuDNN-6.0`
   `I moved to CUDA-9 and CuDNN-7.0`

As soon as you run Tensorflow as a pod, I can guess that solution `1`,`2`,`3` should be applied to the worker node, but for solution `4` you may need to update your Tensorflow docker image.a